# Where are the runs in this infinite string? (CCCCCC Found!)

Tags: code-challenge, string

Starting with the string `ABC`, consider the result of repeatedly appending the last half of itself to itself (using the larger half if the length is odd).

We get the progression:

```
ABC
ABCBC
ABCBCCBC
ABCBCCBCCCBC
ABCBCCBCCCBCBCCCBC
etc...
```

Let `S` represent the resulting infinite string (or sequence) that results as this procedure is repeated forever.

## Goal

The goal in this code challenge is to find the index of the first occurrence of runs of `C`'s in `S`.

It's easy at first: `C` first occurs at index `2`, `CC` at `4`, `CCC` at `7`, `CCCC` at `26`, but `CCCCC` is all the way at index `27308`! After that my memory runs out.

The winner will be the submission that correctly generates the most run indices (in order, starting at `C`). You can use any sort of algorithm but be sure to explain it if you aren't using basic brute force. The input and output can be in any easy to understand format.

**Important Note:** I do not officially know whether or not `S` actually contains all runs of `C`'s. This question is derived from [this one on the Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/876937/do-runs-of-every-length-occur-in-this-string), in which the author hasn't found `CCCCCC` either. I'm curious if anyone here can.  (That question is in turn based on [my original question on the topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/861836/does-this-sequence-have-any-mathematical-significance).)

If you can prove that not all runs of `C` occur in `S` then you will win automatically since this question will no longer be valid. If no one can prove that nor find `CCCCCC` then the winner will be the person who can get the highest lower bound on the index of `CCCCCC` (or whatever the largest unsolved run is if `CCCCCC` is found).

**Update:** Humongous kudos to [isaacg](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20080/isaacg) and [r.e.s.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3440/r-e-s) who have found `CCCCCC` at the astronomical index of 2.124*10^519. At this rate I can't imagine finding `CCCCCCC` with any method that relies on brute force. Good work guys!

Comment: I don't get it - You're saying you've found `CCCCC` at index 27308, but later it sounds like you don't know where it first occurs. Did you mean `CCCCCC`?

Comment: @isaacg Oops. 6 C's is the one that's hard to find. I'll fix that.

Comment: If the conjecture is wrong, there is a N for which c^N is the longest run. I'm pretty sure it should be possible to construct a longer sequence, leading to a contradiction and proving the conjecture. I also don't think it's too hard, but on the other hand problems can easily underestimated...

Comment: I am definitely coming back here at midnight with my new batch of votes - for both the question and the answers!

Comment: For those who are searching, this can make it a bit easier:
If you remove the first "A" then you only have to play with "AB" and you append half+1 for the next iteration.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## CCCCCC found at 2.124*10^519.

Precise index is 2124002227156710537549582070283786072301315855169987260450819829164756027922998360364044010386660076550764749849261595395734745608255162468143483136030403857241667604197146133343367628903022619551535534430377929831860918493875279894519909944379122620704864579366098015086419629439009415947634870592393974557860358412680068086381231577773140182376767811142988329838752964017382641454691037714240414750501535213021638601291385412206075763857490254382670426605045419312312880204888045665938646319068208885093114686859061215

Found by r.e.s., using the (old version of) code below, after 3.5 hours of searching.

Around that index, the string is: `...BCCBCBCCCBCCCCCCBCCB...`

To verify, change the indicated line in the code below to start at 2946, instead of 5. Verification takes 20 seconds.

**Update: Improved program. Old program searched ~10x more locations than necessary.**

New version finds the `CCCCCC` in only 33 minutes.

How the code works: Basically, I only look at the regions which correspond to the ends of incremental strings, and calculate the letters by looking recursively back to the original string. Note that it uses a memo table, which may fill up your memory. Put a cap on the length of the memo table if necessary.

```pyth
import time
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(4000)
ULIMIT=4000
end_positions=[]
current_end=2
while len(end_positions)<ULIMIT+3:
    end_positions.append(current_end)
    next_end=((current_end+1)*3+1)//2-1
    current_end=next_end
memo={}
def find_letter(pos):
    if pos in memo:
        return memo[pos]
    if pos<3:
        return 'ABC'[pos]
    for end_num in range(len(end_positions)-1):
        if pos>end_positions[end_num] and pos<=end_positions[end_num+1]:
            delta=end_positions[end_num+1]-end_positions[end_num]
            if len(memo)>5*10**6:
                return find_letter(pos-delta)
            memo[pos]=find_letter(pos-delta)
            return memo[pos]
time.clock()
for end_num in range(5,ULIMIT+1): # This line.
    diff = 1 # Because end_num is guaranteed to be a C
    while True:
        last_letter=find_letter(end_positions[end_num]+diff)
        if not last_letter=='C':
            break
        diff+=1
    if end_num%100==0:
        pos_str=str(end_positions[end_num])
        print(end_num,'%s.%s*10^%i'%(pos_str[0],pos_str[1:5],len(pos_str)-1),
        len(memo),diff,time.clock())
    if diff>=6:
        print(end_num,end_positions[end_num],diff,time.clock())
```

Current max searched to: 4000 iterations

`CCCCCC` found at iteration(s):
2946

Comment: This is Python right?

Comment: Yeah, I'll add that.

Comment: (+1) Your program, with `sys.setrecursionlimit(4000)` and 
`ULIMIT=4000`, found (in about 3.5 hours on my system) the first occurrence of CCCCCC at index = 2.124*10^519. The exact index is in the next comment ...

Comment: 2124002227156710537549582070283786072301315855169987260450819829164756027922998360364044010386660076550764749849261595395734745608255162468143483136030403857241667604197146133343367628903022619551535534430377929831860918493875279894519909944379122620704864579366098015086419629439009415947634870592393974557860358412680068086381231577773140182376767811142988329838752964017382641454691037714240414750501535213021638601291385412206075763857490254382670426605045419312312880204888045665938646319068208885093114686859061215

Comment: Awesome! I never suspected it was so close to succeeding.

Comment: @r.e.s. I'll edit that into my answer, and verify it on my machine.

Comment: No wonder @Calvin'sHobbies ran out of memory. Basically useless information, but damn do I find it cool.

Comment: This is amazing you guys! This problem is more insane than I thought.

Answer (score 12):

#### CCCCCC found at 2.124*10^519.

The following ruby code was used to search for `CCCCCC`.

```
SEARCH = 6

k = [5,3]

getc=->i{
  j=i
  k.unshift(k[0]+(k[0]+1)/2)while(k[0]<=j)
  k.each_cons(2){|f,g|j-=f-g if j>=g}
  "ABC"[j]
}

while true
  x=k[0]
  x-=1 while getc[x]=="C"
  x+=1 
  l=1
  l+=1 while getc[x+l]=="C"

  break if l>=SEARCH
end

puts x
puts (x-14..x+l+13).map{|i|getc[i]}*""
```

The index is the same as in [@isaacg](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20080/isaacg)'s answer.

The runtime of above code for 6 is in the order of ten seconds on my computer. Nevertheless, it is still search for an answer for `CCCCCCC` (if you want to try it yourself set constant `SEARCH` to `7`).

You can use `getc` to find the character at a specific position `i` as it is done in the last line where the string around the index is printed.

Comment: Good job speeding it up - my solution was very rough and unpolished.

Comment: Something weird: I've run the above code up to iteration #34000 after removing the break and changing the tests around a bit, and it only finds the one run of 6. Is this a problem with the code (I doubt it) or is it just an odd property of the sequence?

Comment: @isaacg Note that we only check on the breaks of each sequence and thus miss all the copy-sequences C^6. At the breaks those seem to be very rare - thus I think we won't see a C^7 soon.

Comment: I know, but since one was found on a sequence break after only 2946 iterations, I'd expect to see a second one by 40000 iterations, which is where I am now.

Comment: @isaacg You may use the (much much faster) code here: http://ideone.com/HoEKOB. Even with that I couldn't find another C^6 at a sequence point (even less a C^7).

Comment: Awesome! That's really far out there. I wonder why there's such a big gap,.

Comment: @isaacg The next one: C^6 @ 8.582*10^11815, after 67070 iterations. Can anyone run the code (http://ideone.com/HoEKOB) on a faster machine than my laptop :-)

Comment: Um, did you misprint the iteration number, or did you not change the index number in your previous comment?

Comment: Oh, also, how long did it take?

Comment: Only 1900 seconds. It finds the first C^6 after 400 milliseconds.

Comment: Impressive. That's something like 31500 times faster than the original code that found the first C^6.

Comment: I'm trying out the code on my desktop, we'll see if it's faster.

Comment: Alright, I found the second C^6, right where you said it was, but it took me 3900 seconds. I'm using my computer for a bunch of other tasks, though. Also, I got 67098 iterations, not 67070. Same index #, though.

Comment: Just FYI ... I ran your Java program with SEARCH=7 until it terminated (in about **18 hours**) due to "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space". In that time it found nothing beyond the already-reported second "sequence point"-occurrence of C^6, which it had found in 4800 seconds.

Comment: @r.e.s. Just FYI: the 6th C^6 comes at iteration 177684 @ 1.45*10^31289.

Comment: Thanks ... What was the running-time for that? I notice that the number of times C^k occurs at sequence points, before the first occurence of C^(k+1), has so far been a non-decreasing sequence. E.g., C^5 occurs this way about 125 times before C^6 appears. This might suggest that C^7 won't appear until C^6 has occurred **well over 125 times** at sequence points. If there are only 6 of these occurrences in 177684 iterations, the first C^7 might indeed be inaccessibly *waaaaay out there*.

Comment: @r.e.s. It was at 51024 seconds. I only gave 4g heap memory to the jvm and the gc was already eating up 90% of the performance.

Comment: For a 3x faster Ruby program: in the `while true` loop, just change `x=k[0]` to `x=k[0]-1` and delete the next two lines (the lines beginning with `x-=` and `x+=`). This works because every intermediate string ends in 'BC'.

Answer (score 5):

(Not an answer, but too long for a comment.)

The following is a Python translation of [@Howard's Ruby program](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/35258/3440) (sped up by a factor near 3 by having only one `getc` in the search loop). On my system, this finds the first C^6 in 3 seconds. In 93 hours, it finds no C^7 in 231,000 iterations, so the first C^7 (if it exists) must occur after the leftmost 10^40677 positions in the infinite string.

```
import time

L = [5, 3]      #list grows "backwards" (by insertion on the left)

def getc(i):    #return the letter at index i
    while L[0] <= i: L.insert(0,L[0] + (L[0] + 1)//2)
    for k in range(len(L)-1): 
        if i >= L[k+1]: i -= L[k] - L[k+1]
    return 'abc'[i]

def search(k):  #find the first occurrence of c^k
    start = time.time()
    iter = 0
    while True:
        iter += 1
        if iter % 1000 == 0: print iter, time.time()-start
        p = L[0] - 1
        l = 1
        while getc(p+l)=='c': l += 1
        if l == k: break 
    return p, iter, time.time()-start

k = 6

(indx, iter, extime) = search(k)
print 'run length:', k
print 'index:', indx, '    (',len(str(indx)),'digits )'
print 'iteration count:', iter
print 'neighborhood:', ''.join([getc(i) for i in range(indx-1,indx+k+10)])
print 'execution time:', extime
```

Comment: With PyPy, it finds C^6 in less than a second on my machine.